# Electron.js 11.0.4 - BrowserWindow is not a contructor

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm going through [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2RxHQoiDctI). I remade the code a little to fit it to Electron 11 according to the docs. The most important is **index.js** file as follows:

```
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');


const notifyBtn = document.getElementById('notifyBtn');

notifyBtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {

    const modalPath = path.join('file://', __dirname, 'add.html');

    let win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 400,
        height: 200,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            enableRemoteModule: true
        }
    });

    win.on('close', () => { win = null });
    win.loadURL(modalPath);
    win.show();
});
```

The above code checks if button from **index.html** file has been clicked and creates new *BrowserWindow* where puts **add.html** content. Here's **index.html** code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="price-container">
            <p class="subtext">Current BTC USD</p>
            <h1 id="price">Loading...</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="goal-container">
            <p><img src="../assets/img/up.png" alt=""><span id="targetPrice">Choose a Target Price</span></p>
        </div>
        <div id="right-container">
            <button id="notifyBtn">Notify me when...</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When the app is running and I try to click the button I get the following error in DevTools console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: BrowserWindow is not a constructor
 at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>
```

Could you tell me please why that error occures? I'm new at Electron. Thank you in advance for all answers!

Comment: Your main script runs in a node context, and opens the BrowserWindow, i.e. the Chrome Instance. The code in your question however doesn't; it runs *inside* the browser. Why would you try to open a new Chrome Instance from inside the first one? If that is actually what you want, you have to send back a message to the node code and open the BrowserWindows there.

Comment: I don't know if I get you good but this is not **main.js** file. main.js is actually the same like in docs example. The code above comes from file which should serve event that display new BrowserWindow (not main app BrowserWindow).

Comment: I know, I assume the JS code in your question is loaded by `<script src="index.js"></script>`, correct? That's why it doesn't work, see [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/quick-start#main-and-renderer-processes). As far as I can tell, you're trying to run `Main` code from a `Renderer` script. Again, why do you want to open a secondary window from inside your first window? Because that is what you're attempting to do. If you want to navigate to `add.html` when the button is clicked, all you need is `window.location = "add.html";`

Comment: To be honest I don't know why **add.html** should be opened as the other window - I'm going throught the tutorial (link is inside question above) and that's what this tutorial contain :D However I'd like to make this feature as new window in order to learn how to make it good in future.

Comment: I don't know either, and I don't think you want to do that in the first place, but that is what your code attempts to do, since I assume you just copied the main part into your renderer script without understanding why that won't work (I'll also go out on a limb and claim that the tutorial didn't tell you to do that, but I'm not going to watch an hour of it). Anyway, the misleading answer below did teach you how to send a message to the main context from the renderer context so I guess it all worked out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a new window through a call to `new BrowserWindow()` is usually done from the **main process**. From a **renderer process**, you need to make use of the [remote](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/remote) API.

> The remote module provides a simple way to do inter-process
> communication (IPC) between the renderer process (web page) and the
> main process.
>
> In Electron, GUI-related modules (such as dialog, menu etc.) are only
> available in the main process, not in the renderer process. In order
> to use them from the renderer process, the ipc module is necessary to
> send inter-process messages to the main process. With the remote
> module, you can invoke methods of the main process object without
> explicitly sending inter-process messages, similar to Java's RMI.

BTW, you could have checked that BrowserWindow is indeed `undefined`, therefore not a constructor, by logging its value to the DevTools console:

```
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
console.log (BrowserWindow); // -> undefined
```

So, in order to get a proper BrowserWindow constructor, you must write indeed:

```
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron').remote;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! Yes I tried make it like `const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron').remote;` but then the DevTools console throws:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'BrowserWindow' of 'require(...).remote' as it is undefined `

Comment: That would probably mean that, in your **main process** (in `main.js` or equivalent), `enableRemoteModule: true` has not been added to the options passed to your call to `new BrowserWindow()` creating the first main window of your app...

Comment: You are a genius!!! I've added this property inside main.js BrowserWindow constructor and everything is working now. Thank you very much for help!